# How can I safely send email over encrypted connection from the command line?

Tags: centos, command-line, email, ssl, smtp

I found the following related questions on the stackexchange network:

- [stackoverflow - Connecting to smtp.gmail.com via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516754/connecting-to-smtp-gmail-com-via-command-line)
- [serverfault - Using nc.exe (NetCat) to send emails to secured SMTP server (TLS)](https://serverfault.com/questions/430629/using-nc-exe-netcat-to-send-emails-to-secured-smtp-server-tls)
- [stackoverflow - How to send email using simple SMTP commands via Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046135/how-to-send-email-using-simple-smtp-commands-via-gmail)

But except for the last one, they are all talking about Windows or Debian and specify software that I've been unable to find for RHEL/CentOS (e.g. `msmtp-mta`).

The last linked solution seems okay (as in, may possibly work on CentOS) but it requires the password to be entered in cleartext on the command line (in a perl one-liner) to get a base64 encoded string, and then requires the base64 encoded string to be entered later on during a run of openssl.  This is relatively insecure as even assuming I've disabled the `bash` history for that command, the base64 string isn't encrypted and is itself stored in the terminal history, the clipboard and who knows where else.  Also, whenever possible I work in a virtual terminal, and thus **I would prefer to have a solution which doesn't require copy and paste at all.**

I would also prefer to have a solution which *would* work even in a business environment—i.e. **when my email password is entered, it shouldn't even be echoed to the screen** (just like a `bash` login).

So again, the exact question is: **How can I *safely* send an email from a gmail account via the command line on CentOS?**

Comment: Please don't use [this](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere) or [here](http://uxmovement.com/content/why-your-links-should-never-say-click-here/) links, but provide a meaningful phrase for the link. That increases your chance of getting a response.

Comment: Fixed.  They're all on stackexchange; I would never have done that otherwise, but now I realize that there was no way for a reader to determine that before my edit.

Comment: Your edit didn't change a thing, it still shows **this** links. I edited your question to show you how to insert links the recommended way.

Comment: Got it now (and I read the articles you linked in your first comment.)

Answer (score 1):

See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27787547/5008284) on how to install msmtp on CentOS from the Epel repository.

In your `~/.msmtprc` config file you can put your cleartext password, or set `passwordeval` to the name of
a command to get your password by whatever means you want.

Comment: Is there a way to tell it to input the password such that it isn't stored in cleartext or shown in cleartext anywhere?  (That's a big part of my original question.)

Comment: As I mentioned, you can set `passwordeval` to a command that returns the password.  The man page gives an example of calling gpg to decrypt a file holding a password. This would require you to setup gpg and give a (different) gpg password to decrypt the file.  There are many articles on how to use gpg.